# Why won't input stream find a file outside of the class folder

Tags: java, spring, file-io, inputstream

I want to want to use input stream with a file "NewFile.java", the code I have works fine if the file is situated in the same folder as the .class file that is performing the action. But once I move I get null reference.

I have tried using absolute and relative paths with and without a '/' at the start.

```
InputStream in = getClass()
                .getResourceAsStream("NewFile.java");
```

I would like to source the file when it is located in the root directory of the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better use InputStream in= new FileInputStream(new File("path/to/yourfile"));

The way you are using it now is as a resource which has to be in the class path.

Comment: This seems like the most straight forward answer and it worked, I have a question though. If this application would be running from an online repository can we still use this with the file path as a parameter? If we use the relative path eg. 
`InputStream in1= new FileInputStream(new File("NewFile.java"));`

Answer (score 2):

`getResourceAsStream()` is not meant to open arbitrary files in the filesystem, but opens resource files located in java packages. So the name "/com/foo/NewFile.java" would  look for "NewFile.java" in the package "com.foo". You cannot open a resource file outside a package using this method.

Comment: ...replace "java packages" with "classpath", then I agree :)  (some people could consider "no/empty package"/"the default package" as "outside" :)

Comment: @xerx593 Hm, where exactly do you see the difference?

Answer (score 1):

There is a distinction between *files* on the file system, and *resources*, on the class path. In general a .java source file won't be copied/added to the class path.

For a class `foo.bar.Baz` and a resource `foo/bar/images/test.png` one can use

```
Baz.class.getResourceAsStream("images/test.png")
Baz.class.getResourceAsStream("/foo/bar/images/test.png")
```

As you see the paths are *class paths*, possibly inside .jar files.

Use file system paths:

```
Path path = Paths.get(".../src/main/java/foo/bar/Baz.java");
InputStream in = Files.newInputStream(path);
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path);
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
Files.copy(path, ...);
```